# Bad file descriptor, read, while extracting zip file using node-stream-zip

Tags: node.js, zip

I have a zip file that has a folder like

```
1234/pic1.png
1234/pic2.png
1234/data.xlsx
```

I am trying to extract the spreadsheet (failing that, all files) using node-stream-zip.

```
const StreamZip = require('node-stream-zip');
const zip = new StreamZip({
        file: path.join(downloadsDir, fileToFind),
        storeEntries: true
    });
zip.on('ready', () => {

    if(!fs.existsSync('extracted')) {
        fs.mkdirSync('extracted');
    }

    zip.extract('1234/', './extracted', err => {
        console.log(err);

    });
   zip.close();
});
```

This produces

> EBADF: bad file descriptor, read

In the extracted folder is one of the png files. But when following the [guide](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-stream-zip) to extract just the xlsx file it appears that the xlsx file is the one causing this error.

```
   zip.extract('1234/data.xlsx', './extracted.xlsx', err => {
       console.log(err);       
    });
```

Is the problem with the xlsx file? I can open it manually. Is it permissions-related? Node? This particular package?

Comment: `zip.close()` is "outside" of he `extract()` function callback. Because these are async methods that means it's closing the zip file before you actually do anything. Hence the "bad file descriptor" by the method trying to "extract" on  a closed file descriptor. Put the `.close()` "inside" the callback method. Just like the documentation actually shows you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is related to `zip.close()`. You're closing it on the same tick as you're invoking `zip.extract()`.